# How to apply styling to select using JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have been trying to add styling to select using JQuery UI in my jsp file. But I am not able to do so. I have watched plenty of tutorials and also looked in demos provided by the official site of JQuery for the selectmenu but I am unable to do so in my select menu. Whether my linking to my JQuery UI files is correct can someone please tell me what is wrong with the above code. Thanks in advance

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import= "java.util.*,java.Date.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import= "javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/call_for_report.css"/>
    <!-- References to JQuery UI packages goes here -->
    <script src="JQ-UI/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQ-UI/external/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="JQ-UI/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <title>Call For Report</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#field_name').selectmenu() ;
        }) ;
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kn"
                   user ="root" password="password"/>

 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
        SELECT name FROM sites ;
 </sql:query>

    <fieldset>

        <form onsubmit="" action="view.jsp" method="JSP">

            <center>

            <h2 id="heading">
                <u><i>Select a Button For Viewing</i></u>
            </h2>   

                <div id="field_menu">
                <label for="field_name">Select The Field Name</label>
                <select name="field_name" id="field_name" style="width: 150px;">
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                        <option><c:out value="${row.name}"/></option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
                </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value ="Production Report" class="styling" name="view" id="top_button">
                <input type="submit" value ="Work Over History" class="styling" name="view">
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Crane Job History" class="styling" name="view">
                <input type="submit" value="Well Sickness History" class="styling" name="view">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Liquid Level History" class="styling" name="view" id="bottom_button">

            </center>
        </form>
    </fieldset>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you referring to linking the style sheets within your project? does the file exist within the path? `JQ-UI/jquery-ui.css`?

Comment: Include `jquery.js` before `jquery-ui.js`, as the latter is dependent on the former..

Comment: Thanks John S it works.